# Ionic building an IOS application

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

I have finished building and compiling the Android version of the application from my windows laptop.

But to run it on IOS, am I supposed to copy the application folder to a MAC computer and run "ionic run ios"?

Comment: You may need Xcode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow these steps.

Check whether Ionic is already installed in Mac by typing `ionic -v`.

- If Ionic is already installed, type the following commands:

  1. `ionic platform add ios`.
  2. `ionic build ios`.
- If Ionic is not installed yet,

  1. First install Node.js in Mac.
  2. Then install Cordova and Ionic by using this command:

     ```
     npm install -g cordova ionic
     ```

Once done with the installation, use the above commands for adding platform and build.

Then you will able to see Xcode file in platform folder iOS.

Then you can ask iOS developer to generate ipa file for iOS build.

Answer (score 1):

You should add ionic ios platform before build

```
ionic platform add ios
```

Read this link : [Ionic build](http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/installation.html)